# Checking if index is null and providing an error?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I have the following code:

```
 Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click ' calculate button
    If String.IsNullOrEmpty(TextBox1.Text) Then
        MsgBox("Please enter a value to convert!")
    End If

    If currentIndex = vbNull Then
        MsgBox("Please select a conversion!")
    End If

    Select Case currentIndex
        Case 1
            Label2.Text = TextBox1.Text & " Celsius = " & Math.Round(((TextBox1.Text * 1.8) + 32), 2) & " Fahrenheit"
        Case 2
            Label2.Text = TextBox1.Text & " Fahrenheit = " & Math.Round(((TextBox1.Text - 32) / 1.8), 2) & " Celsius"
        Case 3
            Label2.Text = TextBox1.Text & " Kelvin = " & Math.Round((TextBox1.Text - 273.15), 2) & " Celsius"
        Case 4
            Label2.Text = TextBox1.Text & " Celius = " & Math.Round((TextBox1.Text + 273.15), 2) & " Kelvin"
        Case 5
            Label2.Text = TextBox1.Text & " Kelvin = " & Math.Round((((TextBox1.Text - 273.15) * 1.8) + 32), 2) & " Fahrenheit"
        Case 6
            Label2.Text = TextBox1.Text & " Fahrenheit = " & Math.Round(((((TextBox1.Text - 32) * 5) / 9) + 273.15), 2) & " Kelvin"
        Case 8
            Label2.Text = TextBox1.Text & " Miles P/H = " & Math.Round((TextBox1.Text * 1.609344), 2) & " Kilometers P/H"
        Case 9
            Label2.Text = TextBox1.Text & " Kilometers P/H = " & Math.Round((TextBox1.Text / 1.609344), 2) & " Miles P/H"
        Case 11
            Label2.Text = TextBox1.Text & " Kilograms = " & Math.Round((TextBox1.Text * 2.20462), 2) & " Pounds"
        Case 12
            Label2.Text = TextBox1.Text & " Pounds = " & Math.Round((TextBox1.Text / 2.20462), 2) & " Kilograms"
        Case 14
            Label2.Text = TextBox1.Text & " Meters = " & Math.Round((TextBox1.Text * 3.2808399), 2) & " Feet"
        Case 15
            Label2.Text = TextBox1.Text & " Feet = " & Math.Round((TextBox1.Text / 3.2808399), 2) & " Meters"
    End Select
End Sub
```

As you can see, I have a variable (currentIndex) and have a select case statement checking them against the various conversions, however my problem lies in the piece of code above this.

```
If currentIndex = vbNull Then
    MsgBox("Please select a conversion!")
End If
```

I require it to spit an error message out if the index is null, however I cannot work out a way to do this. 0 cannot be used as this is the first entry in the index, and vbNull etc do not seem to work. Can anybody point me in the right direction? Thanks.

EDIT:
This is how current index is created:

```
Dim currentIndex As Integer
```

and this is how it is assigned:

```
Private Sub ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ListBox1.SelectedIndexChanged

    ' Get the currently selected index of the item in the list box.
    currentIndex = ListBox1.FindString(currentItem)
End Sub
```

Comment: what type is `currentIndex`?

Comment: Can you show the code where currentIndex is created, and where it is assigned a value?

Comment: @RyanHenderson I have updated the code in my original post

Comment: Inetegers can never be null, so no.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest using SelectedIndex instead.

In your code:

```
    If ListBox1.SelectedIndex = -1 Then
        MsgBox("Please select a conversion!")
    End If
```

Here is the reference for the property: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.selectedindex.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If currentIndex is an index from dropdown box then value of -1 means that nothing was selected.

Comment: It's a ListBox, however upon trying the code  `If currentIndex = -1 Then
            MsgBox("Please select a conversion!")
        End If` it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Can u check in a debugger what *is* the value?